# Error: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I have the following code:

```vb
    set ors1 = server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

    sqlString = "USE PoSystem OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY WebUsersPasswordEncryption DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE EncryptUsersPasswords "&_
                "SELECT UserName,JobTitle,UserRoleID,FullName,EntityID,StatusID,CONVERT(nvarchar(50),DECRYPTBYKEY(Password)) AS  PASSWORD,Email,BeneficiaryID,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, LastLoginDate)) AS LastLoginDate "&_
                "FROM TblWebUsers WHERE UserID="&UserID&" CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY WebUsersPasswordEncryption"  
    ors1.Open sqlString,conn,3,1

                UserName    = ors1("UserName")
                Remark      = ors1("JobTitle")
                PassWord    = ors1("PassWord")
                Email       = ors1("Email")
                UserRoleID  = ors1("UserRoleID")
                StatusID    = ors1("StatusID") 
                Entity      =  ors1("EntityID")
                userFullName= ors1("FullName")
                BeneficiaryID = ors1("BeneficiaryID")
                LastLoginDate = ors1("LastLoginDate")


     ors1.Close
```

But I'm getting the following message:

```
Operation is not allowed when the object closed
on ors1("UserName")
```

How can I solve it? I tried to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` but it's not working.

Comment: There's probably no data being returned. Check your SQL string in SQL Server Management studio.

Comment: And please turn `Option Explicit` on...

Comment: thx paul but it's still not working :(

Comment: here description error exactly: http://postimg.org/image/4hbcztghp/

Comment: I can't see that site, Saleem, try including this image in your post above.

Comment: That site is dodgy at best I wouldn't recommend linking to it why don't you just upload your image through the [so] image upload facility? You obviously had it in the first place to upload to that spam filled site.

Comment: @Lankymart: saleem doesn't have the necessary reputation to be allowed to post images.

Comment: @Martha Then ask for it to be added, the link as it stands is spam.

Comment: It's also worth, in future, including your connection string in the code and a tag indicating the database that you're using (e.g. [tag:ms-access] or [tag:sql-server]).

Answer (score 1):

As @Paul mentioned in the comments, if you query doesn't return any records, you're going to get an error when you try to access the row values.

Guard against this error by testing to see if the `Recordset` is at the end (`EOF`). For example:

```vb
ors1.Open sqlString,conn,3,1

' Make sure recordset isn't empty...
If Not ors1.EOF Then

    UserName    = ors1("UserName")
    Remark      = ors1("JobTitle")
    PassWord    = ors1("PassWord")
    ...

Else
    ' Query returned no records
End If
```

If you need to process multiple records, use a loop:

```vb
ors1.Open sqlString,conn,3,1

Do Until ors1.EOF
    UserName    = ors1("UserName")
    Remark      = ors1("JobTitle")
    PassWord    = ors1("PassWord")
    ...
    ors1.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: i can't do EOF cuz i have error:Operation is not allowed when the object closed

Comment: The problem is not `.EOF` in this instance, the issue is a closed recordset is returned which means the `SELECT` has never run if it was no data being returned it would be an open recordset but with the `.EOF` property set to `True`.

Comment: @Lankymart - You're correct. Attempting to read from an empty recordset, as I assumed, appears to cause error `80020009 - Exception occurred` instead.

Comment: It's a good answer anyway just OP should have provided the connection details in the first place, would have saved the effort.

Answer (score -1):

I found my problem 
needed to change connection string
from:

```
ConnStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='10.1.1.1';Initial Catalog='***';Uid=***;Pwd=*****;"
```

I change it to:

```
ConnStr="Driver={SQL Server};Server=10.1.1.1;Database=****;Uid=**;Pwd=*****;"
```

Comment: No wonder you were getting a closed recordset you didn't even have the correct provider.